# Find sub string in the column value

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Have `page` table in the Postgresql database, which save page information. 
During page creation, space is added in the `pagetitle` value, but in code I am finding page object from `pagetitle` -  `Detailed findings`. So there is any way to find this. (like substring in python `>>> "abc".__contains__("a")`

code is:

```
>>> page.objects.filter(pagetitle = "Detailed findings", doc=a)
[]
>>> page.objects.filter(pagetitle = "Detailed findings ", doc=a)
[<page: o-0235931>]
```

Thank you.

Now working

```
>>> page.objects.filter(pagetitle__contains="Detailed findings", doc=a)
[<page: o-0235931>]
>>> page.objects.filter(pagetitle__contains="detailed findings", doc=a)
[]
>>> page.objects.filter(pagetitle__icontains="detailed findings", doc=a)
[<page: o-0235931>]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [contains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#contains) or case-insensitive [icontains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#icontains) lookup:

```
page.objects.filter(pagetitle__contains="Detailed findings", doc=a)
```